# faking an air bubble physics

Tags: modeling, physics

Is there a way to make an object to act like an air bubble inside a bottle that will always float to the top and stay inside the bottle model no matter what the rotation of the bottle is in.

Comment: Why would ppl vote to close this question? Do you have a better way of asking this, so you don't vote that way, or is this already solved, and you rather just want this closed instead of sending me the source?

Comment: Did you try to use forces?

Comment: I think that I understand what you are asking, but a couple of images of the sort of thing you want to achieve would go a long way to clarifying things

Comment: do you absolutely need physics or can you just fake it?

Comment: @Sazerac I don't have images, but you have probably seen for example a water bottle and when it moves around there is an air pocket at the top and if the bottle falls to its side then the air pocket spreads out and fills the highest point of the bottle.

Comment: @moonboots I could fake it if it's just a still image, but I might be doing more animation of a few little clear plastic bottles kinda like eye dropper bottles and if I do animation I don't think I could fake it and still make it realistic looking.